# OpenXML (Excel) Invalid URI: A port was expected because of there is a colon (':') present but the port could not be parsed

Tags: openxml

Currently I am using OpenXML to open my excel workbook,
so my code is like below:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ExcelFilePath, true))
```

But If the excel file contains a cell text with hyperlink 192.168.0.1:88888 then it failed to open the excel document, and return this error message:

Exception:System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: A port was expected because of there is a colon (':') present but the port could not be parsed.

Anyone know if any idea how to skip this error or any workaround?

Sample: http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1368761562

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the issue and your file is no longer available. Can you give more specifics about the contents of the file?

Comment: A couple years late...but there's no port **88888**. You probably (definitely) meant 192.168.0.1:8888. Four 8s, not five!